# How to add moq to a working mstest unit test

Tags: moq, mstest

I am using MSTest to write unit tests, but I have been tasked with adding moq to the unit test.  I understand that if an integration test is done in which a file system, a database is normally called, that mocking is essentially allowing for the testing without actually making those "real" calls. I have looked around and just need some help.

I was starting with some basic utilities that I found and started with some basic testing of them with Asserts.  However, I'm needing to take it to the next step and leverage MOQ.

Here is a method that I am testing:

```
    public static bool IsStringEmptyOrNull(string strValue)
    {
        if(null != strValue)
        {
            strValue = strValue.Trim().ToLower();
            return (string.Empty == strValue || "undefined" == strValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Then I have a Test that looks like this:

```
  using System;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
  using Company.W.Utilities;


namespace CESUtilities.Tests
{
[TestClass]
public class When_string_is_empty_or_null
{
    private string empty;
    private string isnull;
    private bool expected;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        empty = "";
        isnull = null;
        expected = true;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void when_string_is_empty()
    {

        bool actual = Util.IsStringEmptyOrNull(empty);   
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void when_string_is_null()
    {
        bool actual = Util.IsStringEmptyOrNull(isnull);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }



    [TestCleanup()]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {

    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  Mocks/stubs are only required to remove external dependencies that the class under test collaborates with.  The example above doesn't require the use of mocks.

Comment: The question would be, how do I add in moq?  Let us pretend that the method "IsStringEmptyOrNull"  needs to be "mocked" so as to NOT call it directly but more of a "fake" call to mimic its behavior.  I realize that it may not seem necessary, but this is a requirement for all new tests to use moq.

Comment: I think the person giving you that requirement does not understand unit testing or mocking. As @Paolo stated, you only need mocking when you want to remove a dependency. Just mocking other stuff is a waste of time and money and will make your code harder to read and maintain. I suggest posting an example where there is an external dependency. In this case we can help you incorporate MOQ

Comment: Actually the guys wanting over 60 projects having test coverage with unit testing and mocks are actually Gods of programming.  It is I who was searching for areas in the project to cherry pick from and tests. I have no problem with admitting my ignorance in various areas of development.  These guru's are out on vacation, and I'm sure that like you are saying they will confirm that this is not what they had in mind.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, as you mentioned you can replace dependencies with mocks. The code you have posted does not contain much in terms of dependencies, but let's pretend it does.

You are testing the method IsStringEmptyOrNull.

Let's suppose that method belongs to a class named Foo (I'm just making stuff up). I'll change the method a bit too.

```
public class Foo
{
    private IBar _bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar; 
    }   

    public static bool IsStringEmptyOrNull(string strValue)
    {
        // dependency is called here
        var readValue = bar.ReadFromFileSystemOrDatabase();

        if(null != strValue 
           && readValue == 1)
        {
            strValue = strValue.Trim().ToLower();
            return (string.Empty == strValue || "undefined" == strValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here you can see that the class Foo has a Bar which is injected in the constructor. Also, it is used in your method. If you do no want your test to actually call this method:

- because it calls to db
- because it calls to filesystem
- you want to isolate the code from the method, from other external code (in this case ReadFromFileSystemOrDatabase()

You can then use a mock to acomplish this. 
Here is how you would do it:

```
// create your mock object
var mockBar = new Mock<IBar>();

// setup a method to return a result when the mock object is called
// notice the return value, which is 1
mockBar.Setup(mock => mock.ReadFromFileSystemOrDatabase()).Returns(1);

// you can then inject the mock object in the object you are testing
var foo = new Foo(mockBar.Object);
```

What will happen is that when your test is run, a mock version of the dependency (in this case Bar) will be given to the class.

When the method will make a call on this mock, if you have *Setup* the method to return a value, it will return this value.

This way you can abstract away dependencies to focus your tests or mock away calls to a db or file system.

As for the exact example you mentioned there isn't anything to mock. Your exact example is not applicable to using mocks.

Mocks aren't something you would do for all your tests.